# why swagger-UI doesn't show prameters and response?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

[image]

I'm using django and djangorestframwork and drf-yasg.
I have this api in **`view.py`** module:

```
@api_view(http_method_names=["GET"])
def get_all__referralCodes_game(request):

    data = request.query_params
    query = GameCollection.find_one(
        {"_id": ObjectId(data["gameId"]),},
        {"_id": 0,f"referralCodes": 1,}
    )
    if query:
        return Response(data={"msg": "ok", "data": [query["referralCodes"]]}, status=http.HTTPStatus.OK)
    return Response(data={"msg": "not_found", "data": {}}, status=http.HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND)
```

and in **`url.py`** module I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("referral-code/get-all", views.get_all__referralCodes_game),
]
```

I need to have `gameId` in query params but it can not be seen there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drf-yasg doesn't know about your `gameId` query parameter. You need to somehow tell it about the parameter.

According to the [drf-yasg documentation](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/openapi.html#default-behavior):

> `query` `Parameters` - i.e. parameters specified in the URL as `/path/?query1=value&query2=value` - are generated from your view’s `filter_backends` and `paginator`, if any are declared. Additional parameters can be specified via the `query_serializer` and `manual_parameters` arguments of `@swagger_auto_schema`.

You could use [`@swagger_auto_schema`](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#the-swagger-auto-schema-decorator) like this:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(
        method='get',
        manual_parameters=[
            openapi.Parameter(
                'gameId',
                openapi.IN_QUERY,
                description='Game ID',
                required=True,
                type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER,
            ),
         ]
)
def get_all__referralCodes_game(request):
```

For the response you can either define a serializer (recommended) and set it as the class's `serializer_class` or you can add a `responses` value to the [`@swagger_auto_schema`](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#the-swagger-auto-schema-decorator) decorator (see the docs for some examples).